# UIView render with wrong height for first time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Running on iPhone 4:

In my one of the view controller I am adding diff. view on segment selection. Like for first segment login view and for second segment registration view.

Here issue is when I start application, for a first time my Login view render on half of the screen only and when I switch to registration view and back to login view again from segment selection, Login view renders correctly (in full screen space).

I have checked height and I am setting it right as per NSLog but still its rendering in half screen only.

```
    if(segIndex == 1){
        [_regObj.view removeFromSuperView];
        _regObj = nil;
        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        _loginObj = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
        rect.origin.y = 60;
        rect.size.height = 360;
        _loginObj.view.frame = rect;
        [self.view addSubview: _loginObj.view];
    }else {
        [_loginObj.view removeFromSuperView];
        _loginObj = nil;
        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        _regObj = [[RegistrationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationView" bundle:nil];
        rect.origin.y = 60;
        rect.size.height = 360;
        _regObj.view.frame = rect;
        [self.view addSubview: _regObj.view];
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: paste your method for segment value change

Comment: Updated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your viewDidLoad method

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)] )
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need setting for LoginView when event of viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear because of looking into your code the loginView displays properly when you get event on Segment Control

Comment: Doing same. Code in original post called from viewDidLoad for first time.